# Change Defination query of a layer in ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, definition-query, dynamic-layer

Is there any solid example to change the definition query at run time of the **ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer** using javascript API 3.5 or higher version and ArcGIS server 10.1. I found API documentation [setdynamiclayerinfos](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#setdynamiclayerinfos) but was not able to find example to find how it exactly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, using this sample from ESRI: http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/map_multiplelayerdef/

put this code in the console:

```
map.getLayer("layer1").setLayerDefinitions(["STATE_NAME='Kansas' and POP2007>250000"]);
```